# What is the difference between feature engineering and feature extraction?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, feature-extraction

I am struggling to find the difference between the two concepts. From what I understand both refer to turning raw data into more comprehensive features to describe the problem at hand. Are they the same thing? If not could anyone please provide examples for both?

Comment: These terms are generally synonymous. A more useful differentiator is between feature engineering and feature selection (constructing high-level statistical patterns that help machine-learning methods learn, vs. removing some of those features that are less useful). I wrote  a primer on this subject here: https://www.featurelabs.com/blog/feature-engineering-vs-feature-selection/

Answer (score 24):

1. **Feature extraction** is usually used when the original data was very different. In particular **when you could not have used the raw data**.

   E.g. original data were images. You extract the redness value, or a description of the shape of an object in the image. It's lossy, but at least you get some result now.
2. **Feature engineering** is the careful preprocessing into more meaningful features, even **if you could have used the old data**.

   E.g. instead of using variables x, y, z you decide to use log(x)-sqrt(y)*z instead, because your engineering knowledge tells you that this derived quantity is more meaningful to solve your problem. You get better results than without.

Comment: Feature extraction: combining existing features to produce a more useful one [According to "Hands on ML with SciKit-Learn, Keras & Tensorflow - Aurelien Geron"]

Answer (score -4):

**Feature engineering** - is transforming raw data into  features/attributes that better represent the underlying structure of your data, usually done by domain experts.

**Feature Extraction** - is transforming raw data into the desired form.